# how to clear the cache when using video_player library flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Currently I'm having a problem using the video_player library: 2.2.3. When I use it, the data is being cached. I don't know how to clear that cache yet. So how do I clear that cache?

```
     @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      widget.url,
      videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(mixWithOthers: true),
    )..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Code is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. As you're new, please also take the [tour]. Thanks

Comment: [This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73014) might give you some idea.